# UPDATE multi tables with SELECT statement results in: target table is not updatable

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Trying to UPDATE tables with SELECT statement and mysql expansion results in in 'target table is not updatable'.

There is a Wordpress multisite with more than twenty urls. And I need to change upload_path in database every time I work on recent installation on localhost. Because I don't want to list all tables one by one I used following SELECT statement:

```
UPDATE (SELECT TABLE_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='mydatabase' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'wp\__\_options') AS T
    SET `T`.`option_value` ='/....../wp-content/uploads/'
    WHERE `T`.`option_name` = 'upload_path';
```

Select statement gives me:

```
+--------------+
| TABLE_NAME   |
+--------------+
| wp_2_options |
| wp_3_options |
| wp_5_options |
| wp_6_options |
| ...          |
| ...          |
+--------------+
```

But complete code results in: *[HY000][1288] The target table T of the UPDATE is not updatable*

Comment: In mysql you can't use a subquery  o you have an error  ..   .you could use a update with join.  but you are trying to use the select result for obtain the name of the table this is not allowed  directly in SQL for this you should take a look at dinamyc sql  (building the query dinamically server side)

Comment: One option, in MySQL and MariaDB, is to use a stored procedure [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html)/[MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-procedure/) that uses a
cursor [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html)/[MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/cursor-overview/) and prepared statements [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)/[MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/prepare-statement/).

Comment: In recent versions of MariaDB you can use sentences like [FOR](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/for/) and [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/execute-immediate/).

Comment: Dear scaisEdge and wchiquito, thank you very much for your advice! I first will have a look at Mariadb -> FOR and EXECUTE IMMEDIATE before I will invest in dynamic sql.